# Does "hopelessly lost" sound awkward?

Tags: grammar, subjective

The expression *hopelessly lost* just sounds awkward in my ears. But it seems to be grammatically correct and googling it finds quite a few links, so it seems to be a valid expression nevertheless.

So, is it just me, or is it generally felt as awkward?

Comment: Sounds fine to me.

Comment: I've heard it what seems like many times, and ii sounds very natural to me. Grammatically, many -ly words can be pressed into service to modify adjectives (participial or other): completely exhausted; worryingly depleted // fairly late; suspiciously quiet. _Semantically_, they may not work at all: fairly nuclear; joyously morose.

Comment: actually **being** hopelessly lost is awkward too, so it fits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds perfectly clear and nicely descriptive to my ears. You are lost without any perceivable hope of getting unlosted!

Answer (score 0):

Not only clear, but an erudite, literary allusion - Dante loses his way at the start of the Divine Comedy, and ends up at the gates of Hades, on which are written, 'Abandon hope all ye who enter here.'

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything awkward in "hopelessly lost". Even in German we say "hoffnungslos verloren".